# Roles de usuarios en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, users-roles

No se si sea un tema recurrente, el de saber cuando trabajar con el esquema de autenticación de Django, cual es la mejor forma de usarlo y extenderlo o si se substituye por uno personalizado, pero siempre con la idea de preservar los mecanismos y funcionalidades de autenticación.

Por lo anterior deseo compartir esta inquietud que tengo sobre algunas probables alternativas o acercamientos de diseño que he pensado acerca de la siguiente situación, con el ánimo de que puedan ayudarme a analizar/proponer o escoger la mejor:

Estoy construyendo una aplicación en donde tengo tres tipos diferentes de usuarios:

- Médico
- Paciente
- Fisioterapeuta

Todos tres usuarios deben poder iniciar sesión en el sistema y existirían relaciones (desde el contexto del objeto de negocio de la aplicación o requerimientos) entre los usuarios Medico con los usuarios pacientes y los 
usuarios Fisioterapeuta con los usuarios Paciente, entendiendo que:

- Un paciente es tratado por un médico
- Un paciente es tratado por un terapeuta
- Un paciente podría tener estos tres roles en el sistema (asumo que esto no sería problema)

Mi inicial idea, es utilizar el esquema de autenticación por defecto de Django (django.contrib.auth)

Inicialmente pensé en el siguiente esquema de entidades, en el cual la tabla/modelo User es equivalente a la tabla auth_user que Django genera automaticamente en nuestra base de datos cuando aplicamos nuestra primera migración, y en la cual los usuarios de Django son almacenados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla User yo tengo tres campos boolenos que he adicionado los cuales son: 
`is_patient`, `is_medical` and `is_physiotherapist`

El anterior, creo que es un acercamiento que me permitiría hacer lo que busco, solo que hay un detalle y es que el modelo de autenticación por defecto de Django, no se puede modificar, es inmutable, pensaría que para modificarlo habría que modificar el core de Django y esto es algo mas dispendioso o habría que hacerlo bien o saber que es lo que se esta haciendo.

Por esta razón, los campos `is_patient`, `is_medical` and `is_physiotherapist` no pueden ser adicionados a la tabla User como lo pretendo.

Una recomendación clásica que nos da Django en su documentación es [extender el modelo User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) con una relación OneToOne a otro modelo que contenga los datos adicionales que queremos agregar a los usuarios.
Un ejemplo básico de esto que digo es esta siguiente figura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es de esta forma en como yo puedo conseguir que los usuarios que tengo en Django (gestionados por el esquema de autenticación por defecto de Django `django.contrib.auth`) puedan tener atributos adicionales como una foto, fecha de nacimiento, entre otros que deseemos.

En relación a esto último, el esquema que presento a continuación, ¿podría resultar útil para manejar los diferentes roles de usuario que necesito?, es decir pacientes, médicos y fisioterapeutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo debo tener relaciones entre estas tablas:

- Usuarios Medicos y Usuarios Pacientes
- Usuarios fisioterapeutas y Usuarios Pacientes
  y asi entre ellas y otras tablas

Con este enfoque, ¿éstas relaciones no se verán afectadas?

Los tres tipos diferentes de usuarios, sus atributos serían almacenados entre las tablas UserProfile y User.

En si la tabla UserProfile tendría todos los campos propios de los usuarios paciente, medico y terapeuta.

¿Es esto una buena práctica en sentido de escalabilidad? Sé que no estarían normalizadas claro está.

---

Porque otra alternativa es pensar en mi enfoque inicial, pero sin los campos booleanos `is_patient`, `is_medical` e `is_physiotherapist` y entonces por transitividad trabajar con los diferentes roles de usuario, es decir asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Además de lo anterior, también se presentan algunas alternativas tales como:

1. Crear una tabla/Modelo llamado Role

Si tengo una tabla/modelo role separado o independiente, y esta estaría relacionada con el modelo de usuarios de Django User entonces podría decir que un User puede tener varios roles.
Este enfoque puede ser útil si yo deseo almacenar información exclusiva acerca de un rol en particular.

2. [Sistema de Permisos y Autorización de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization)

Django Permissions and Authorization
En estos momentos ignoro el grado de granularidad (hasta donde me pemitiría llegar a trabajar con los modelos y sus instancias en cuanto a operaciones con ellos).

He mirado de manera superficial que el sistema de autorización y permisos me permitiría trabajar con las operaciones de crear, editar y eliminar

---

También podría mirar lo de la creación de grupos, POr ejemplo, un grupo llamado Medicos en donde los usuarios medicos pertenezcan a él y que este grupo (y por ende los usuarios que lo componen) pueda tener determinados permisos a ciertos modelos y operaciones. Y asi con los otros tipos de usuarios.

¿Es esto otra buena alternativa?

3. AUTH_USER_MODEL [Creating a Custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Otra alternativa que se presenta para cuando el esquema de Django de manejo de usuarios por defecto, no satisface  los requerimientos que se tienen de autenticación o manejo de usuarios en un proyecto, es substituir o personalizar el modelo de usuarios, pero esto no se si tendria sus desventajas en cuanto a no preservar los mecanismos de autenticación y mas funcionalidades que Django nos provee con su modelo User.

Mi requerimiento de tener un usuario paciente, un usuario medico y un usuario fisioterapeuta, ¿requiere construir un modelo de Usuarios personalizado?

Todo lo que nos muestra Django acerca del manejo de usuarios y de las múltiples cosas que nos permiten hacer con este tema, no es algo que sea complicado en si en un principio, pero por lo que he visto y desde mi punto de vista me atrevo a afirmar que es un tema algo extenso, y por lo mismo, me siento algo confundido para tomar la mejor decisión acorde a lo que necesito.

Si alguien ha hecho algo similar o tiene alguna propuesta de orientación (se que tal vez puede ser un caso muy particular para postearl en una comunidad free), estaría muy agradecido.

Muchas gracias por el tiempo y disculpas por el post tan largo.

Comment: Consulta, ¿quién crea los usuarios del sistema?, ¿es un servicio tipo registro o son creados por el administrador del sistema?

Comment: Los usuarios en la aplicación solamente podrán ser creados por el administrador del sistema y nadie más.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el **modelo** de autenticación por defecto de Django, no se puede modificar"?

Comment: He leido y escuchado que por seguridad este modelo o directamente a la tabla auth_users no se le pueden adicionar datos y por eso la acción de extenderlo relacionandolo con otro modelo que contenga los atributos que le queremos adicionar al modelo de usuarios.

Comment: Pues no es totalmente cierto, si bien es posible extender el usuario para crear un tipo de "perfil", también es posible extender la clase `User` de Django. Estoy creando una respuesta que puede ser un poco extensa. Dame un poco de tiempo entre hoy y mañana, ya que mi hijo esta llorón hoy y mi esposa se ha puesto calentona.

Comment: Es un poco tarde, te dejé la primera parte del post, mañana lo edito y continúo!

Comment: Ahora si, creo que se podría decir que mi respuesta está completa

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Me tomé la molestia de crear un proyecto para poder darle forma a tu caso el cual, dicho sea de paso, lo encuentro bastante interesante ya que es posible que me tope con algo parecido en unos meses para un proyecto.

Creé el proyecto `hospital` (fue lo primero que se me ocurrió) usando Django 1.9. Ahora si, como dijo Jack el destripador, [vamos por partes](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wMvc9Kjkkj8/VZbm7KvQMwI/AAAAAAADyM0/EsYrRqDo4UI/s1600/Jack%2Bel%2BDestripador%2B%25282%2529.jpg).

---

Con respecto a tu comentario:

> Los usuarios en la aplicación solamente podrán ser creados por el administrador del sistema y nadie más.

Esto, a mi parecer, te facilita un poco las cosas, te olvidas de los tediosos registros, crearás tu superusuario (con `createsuperuser`) para luego crear los usuarios del sistema necesarios y, lo más importante, tu (estoy asumiendo que eres el administrador del sistema) serás el que controlarás quién podrá hacer qué. Asumo también que no querrás que te estén molestando cada vez que quieran crear un usuario por lo que les darás las herramientas a otros usuarios con menos privilegios para poder crear pacientes e incluso doctores y fisioterapeutas nuevos, algo así como un "superdoctor".

Recuerda que la **autenticación** (usuarios, passwords) y **autorización** (grupos, permisos) son problemas que tenemos que atacarlos por separado.

Habiendo dicho esto, podemos comenzar entonces con el problema de los usuarios múltiples. Yo me inclinaría por trabajar con tu idea original, extender a `User` para tener los booleanos y manejar tres tipos de perfil para cada uno, creo que esto sería a la vez más facil de manejar cuando quieras entrar a la parte de autorización y agregar por ejemplo a un usuario al grupo `doctor`, `fisioterapeuta` o `paciente`.

Cada grupo tendría sus privilegios y sería posible que un usuario pertenezca a uno o más grupos, por lo que podrías tener un doctor que también sea paciente por ejemplo.

Ahora si, vamos a un poco de código. Comenzaré por contradecir tu afirmación:

> El anterior, creo que es un acercamiento que me permitiría hacer lo que busco, solo que hay un detalle y es que el modelo de autenticación por defecto de Django, no se puede modificar, es inmutable, pensaría que para modificarlo habría que modificar el core de Django y esto es algo mas dispendioso o habría que hacerlo bien o saber que es lo que se esta haciendo.

Pues, no es inmutable. Puedes elegir entre usar [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser)  o `AbstractUser`, la diferencia es que `AbstractBaseUser` es un usuario sin los campos de Django, pero contiene toda la lógica de autenticación, mientras que `AbstractUser` si tiene todos los campos que te regala Django. Lo que haremos entonces es [extender el usuario](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) ya que no queremos crear nuestro propio modelo de usuario sino que queremos agregar algunos campos booleanos.

Primero, le decimos a Django que queremos usar nuestro [propio modelo de usuario](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) (he creado una sola app llamada `usuario`):

```
# settings.py

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'usuario'
]

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuario.User'
```

El modelo customizado. Para no sentirnos tan mal, estoy usando el mismo nombre de tabla que usa Django (`auth_user`):

```
# usuario/models.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Luego, Django mismo te sugiere que lo primero que hagas al extender el usuario es crear las migraciones, asi que corremos el comando y de pasada también creamos un superusuario:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'usuario':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model User
$ python manage.py migrate
...
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
...
```

Con una consulta rápida con `shell` podemos ver los campos nuevos:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from usuario.models import User
>>> User.objects.filter(username='cesar').values('is_medical', 'is_patient', 'is_physiotherapist')
[{'is_patient': False, 'is_physiotherapist': False, 'is_medical': False}]
```

Como acabas de ver, es perfectamente posible extender el usuario. Ahora necesitamos los perfiles. Como los perfiles son solamente una relación `OneToOne` a nuestro usuario, podemos crear todos los perfiles que nos venga en gana (solo crearé un par de campos a cada uno):

```
# usuario/models.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Nuevamente, creamos la migración y migramos:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'usuario':
  0002_medicalprofile_patientprofile_physiotherapistprofile.py:
    - Create model MedicalProfile
    - Create model PatientProfile
    - Create model PhysiotherapistProfile
$ python manage.py migrate
...
```

Listo, ¡ya replicamos tu idea original!

### Autenticación

Veamos si es posible autenticar el usuario. No voy crear todo un login completo, solo haremos uso de [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) para demostrarlo. Hagámoslo desde el `shell`:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> print authenticate(username='cesar', password='password-incorrecto')
None
>>> print authenticate(username='cesar', password='password-correcto')
<User: cesar>
```

Perfecto, funciona. Un dolor de cabeza menos, ya sabemos que incluso habiendo creado nuestro propio modelo de usuario heredado del `User` de Django, el proceso de autenticación funciona como debería. La forma en la que haces la autenticación finalmente es tarea tuya (usando el sistema de autenticación Django, OAuth2, Social Auth, etc.).

### Autorización

Como mencioné anteriormente, bastará por el momento con crear tres grupos: `doctor`, `fisioterapeuta` y `paciente`. Antes de continuar, podemos crear algunas funciones en nuestro modelo `User` para obtener los perfiles de acuerdo al tipo de usuario.

```
# usuario/models.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile = self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_physiotherapist_profile(self):
        physiotherapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'physiotherapistprofile'):
            physiotherapist_profile = self.physiotherapistprofile
        return physiotherapist_profile

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Esto nos ayudará, ya que cuando usas la relación `OneToOneField` y esta relación no existe, te genera el error `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from usuario.models import User
>>> usuario = User.objects.get(username='cesar')
>>> usuario.medicalprofile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cesar/Development/Personal/hospital/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 355, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no medicalprofile.
```

Pero, si usamos nuestra nuevas funciones, no generará error porque estamos validando previamente que existe el atributo:

```
>>> print usuario.get_medical_profile()
None
```

Muy bien, entonces estas funciones nos servirán de mucho. Como ejemplo, en alguna de tus vistas podrías usarlas de esta forma para obtener los perfiles de acuerdo al usuario logueado:

```
def crear_historia_clinica(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_medical:
        profile = user.get_medical_profile()
        # Tal vez el doctor es nuevo y no tiene perfil
        if profile:
            # Mas código
        else:
            # Redireccionar, levantar un error, etc.
    else:
        # Redireccionar, levantar un error, etc.
```

Bien, para ver el tema de los grupos, creemos solo un doctor y un paciente: "Dr. House" y "Jorge Enfermizo". No quiero llenar esto de capturas de pantalla ya que esto es fácil de hacer desde el admin, pero hagámoslo desde el `shell`:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from usuario.models import User
>>> User.objects.create_user(username='Dr. House', password='12345', is_medical=True)
<User: Dr. House>
>>> User.objects.create_user(username='Jorge Enfermizo', password='67890', is_patient=True)
<User: Jorge Enfermizo>
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: cesar>, <User: Jorge Enfermizo>, <User: Dr. House>]
```

Listo, ahora creemos los grupos de los usuarios:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
>>> Group.objects.create(name='doctor')
<Group: doctor>
>>> Group.objects.create(name='fisioterapeuta')
<Group: fisioterapeuta>
>>> Group.objects.create(name='paciente')
<Group: paciente>
>>> Group.objects.all()
[<Group: doctor>, <Group: fisioterapeuta>, <Group: paciente>]
```

Agregamos los usuarios a su grupo correspondiente, digamos que Dr. House también puede ser un paciente:

```
>>> grupo_doctor = Group.objects.get(name='doctor')
>>> grupo_paciente = Group.objects.get(name='paciente')
>>> doctor_house = User.objects.get(username='Dr. House')
>>> doctor_house.groups.add(grupo_doctor, grupo_paciente)
>>> doctor_house.groups.all()
[<Group: doctor>, <Group: paciente>]
>>> jorge_enfermizo = User.objects.get(username='Jorge Enfermizo')
>>> jorge_enfermizo.groups.add(grupo_paciente)
>>> jorge_enfermizo.groups.all()
[<Group: paciente>]
```

Ahora, solo bastará con preguntar para saber si un usuario pertenece a cierto grupo, en algunas de tus vistas:

```
def solo_para_pacientes(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.groups.filter(name='paciente').exists():
        # Tiene los privilegios de este grupo
    else:
        # Redireccionar, levantar un error, etc.
```

Finalmente, solo quedaría que a los grupos creados, les agregues los permisos que quieres que tenga cada uno y en las vistas uses tus mecanismos para comprobar que el usuario pueda hacer solo lo que su grupo le permite.

### Notas finales

Siempre lo digo, no reinventes la rueda a menos que sea por temas didácticos.

Si quieres autenticar usuarios:

- [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit)
- [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)

Si quieres validar la parte de autorización:

- [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian)

Si se te antoja usar registro de usuarios:

- [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration)
- [django-registration-redux](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration)

Si quieres un template gratuito, actualizado y muy bueno:

- [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)

Comment: Cesar muchas gracias por tu ilustrativa respuesta. He visto que al heredar de la clase AbstractUser, cuando migramos, veo que no tenemos en el admin el modulo de User dado que lo hemos personalizado usando AbstractUser, y entonces es necesario registrarlo manual en mi archivo admin.py con los atributos que maneja User en Django.  Al final del día, esto no es problema, se registra.

Comment: Pero veo tambien que cuando creamos un usuario en este nuevo modelo personalizado, sea por consola o por via django admin, el password no sale "hasheado" e incluso en el momento en el que lo ingresamos en el admin cuando creamos un usuario, sale en texto plano, como también cuando se visualizan las opciones del mismo user.  El admin de django y django en general utilizan PBKDF2 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 ) por defecto como mecanismo de cifrado.

Comment: En este post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514912/django-admin-not-hashing-custom-user-password dicen que cuando registramos un modelo que herede de AbstractUser, en la clase que creamos para su registro en el archivo admin.py se debe es heredar de la clase UserAdmin y no de la admin.ModelAdmin que usamos para registrar los modelos en el administrador de Django. Al hacer esto, UserAdmin hace que mi campo password salga cifrado tanto para ser ingresado como cuando lo visualizo.

Comment: El problema es que si cambio a heredar de la clase UserAdmin, los campos que he adicionado a mi modelo de usuario personalizado en este caso is_patient, is_medical e is_physiotherapist no salen en el administrador cuando creamos o editamos un usuario, pues ya usa los de por defecto que tiene el modelo User original y no el personalizado que hemos hecho. ¿Qué mecanismo habría para que con nuestro modelo personalizado quede el password hasheado en el admin o que cuando heredemos de UserAdmin, podamos tambien ver reflejados los campos adicionados en el admin? No se si ha sido clara mi pregunta.

Comment: Personalizado amigo, personalizado.

Comment: Hola @César y como podría usar decoradores para proteger mis vistas, teniendo en cuenta que habrán vistas donde tenga acceso dos tipos de usuarios (paciente y doctor). En espera de tu respuesta

Answer (score 4):

Es muy interesante tu caso de uso, probé una solución un poco mas sencilla, no estoy seguro si cumple a cabalidad con tus requerimientos, en esta solución se puede usar `django.contrib` sin complicaciones para login y demás.

Eso sí agregando cada usuario a un grupo de usuarios de Django para posteriores filtros en los views, un usuario puede pertenecer a N grupos sin problemas, desde el sitio de administración puedes asignar a los usuarios a determinados grupos.

Perdón por la informalidad del código, pero es una vista global de como se puede construir la base de datos, los atributos son valores de pruebas.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 


class Medico(models.Model):
    especialidad = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    usuariomedico = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

class Fisioterapeuta(models.Model):
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    usuariofisio = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

class Paciente(models.Model):
     usuariopaciente = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

class PacienteEspecializado(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Paciente, to_field='usuariopaciente', null=True,blank=True)  
    medico = models.OneToOneField(Medico, to_field='usuariomedico', null=True,blank=True)
    fisioterapeuta = models.OneToOneField(Fisioterapeuta, to_field='usuariofisio', null=True,blank=True)
```

Se me viene a la cabeza que la clase `PacienteEspecializado` puede ser una historia clínica o cualquier otra cosa.

Al registrarlos en `admin.py`, el código sobra pero bueno.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Medico, Fisioterapeuta, Paciente, PacienteEspecializado


admin.site.register(Medico)
admin.site.register(Fisioterapeuta)
admin.site.register(Paciente)
admin.site.register(PacienteEspecializado)
```

Si tienes alguna pregunta o la solución tiene algún error házmelo saber.

Answer (score 2):

Un saludo amigo.
Yo uso un enfoque similar al tuyo, creando grupos de usuarios en Groups de Django.
Extendiendo el modelo con un modelo "Usuario" y un FK hacia User (Todos mis roles requieren los mismos campos).

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usuario')
        ci_ruc = models.CharField(max_length= 13, help_text='Cedula o RUC')
        direccion = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
        telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Loja')
        empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, blank=True, null=True)
        tecnico_externo = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Técnico que no trabaja en la empresa. Se contrata por servicios específicos.')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.usuario.save()
```

Las ultimas funciones aseguran que la creación de un "Usuario" se relacione directamente con la creación de un "User".
Lo hice siguiendo este tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

Otra recomendación es que protejas los templates. No sé que tan recomendable sea puesto que no he hecho protección desde las vistas.
Yo he agregado un templatetag en la app usuarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de user_tags.py:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Stdlib imports

# Core Django imports
from django import template

# Third-party app imports

# Realative imports of the 'app-name' package


register = template.Library()


@register.filter('has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    """
    Verifica se este usuário pertence a um grupo
    """
    groups = user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
    return True if group_name in groups else False
```

Luego simplemente la cargas con "load" en tu template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
 <ul class="nav side-menu">
      {% if user|has_group:"Clientes" %}
         <!-- REPARACIONES -->
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Reparaciones <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
          <ul class="nav child_menu">
            <li><a href="{% url 'reparaciones:list_user' user.pk %}">Mis equipos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      {% else %}
```

Ahora, tu app es requerida para un sólo un hospital.
Mi problema surgió cuando un usuario tiene varios roles en varias empresas, es decir, es técnico en una y cliente en otra, en ese caso se actualizó el fk hacia empresa, y ahora tiene las reparaciones de la empresa en la que es cliente.

Estoy en este dilema, necesitaría extender la tabla

> auth_user_group

y añadir empresa_id. Así podría seleccionar a que empresa pertenece el rol en el que se está desempeñando, y al estar los templates protegidos no tendría acceso a ciertas vistas.
Espero te sirva y te dejo el enfoque, por si tu app crece y la requieras utilizar en múltiples hospitales, y te evites este quebradero de cabeza en el que estoy.

Revisa este tutorial por si te es útil: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Suerte y a programar!

Comment: Excelente enfoque Jose, lo miraré en detalle junto con los recursos que me facilitas. Muchas gracias.