# Heredando de AbstractUser - Django admin no hashea passwords - UserAdmin no muestra datos personalizados de un User

Tags: python, django, django-models, users-roles

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en la cual tengo tres diferentes tipos de usuarios o roles (Paciente, Médico y Fisioterapeuta)

Las inquietudes que enunciaré en esta pregunta se derivan [de este inicial post que hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/930/roles-de-usuarios-en-django) y de la ilustrativa respuesta que obtuve por parte de [@cesar-bustios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/100/c%C3%A9sar-bust%C3%ADos)

Recapitularé un poco la respuesta que obtuve del post anterior que referencio con objetivos de brindar acá en mi pregunta el ejemplo completo y poder tener mas elementos de análisis.

**1.** Se ha creado un modelo de usuarios personalizado
Después de crear el proyecto de Django, cree la aplicación llamada userprofile

```
# settings.py

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'userprofile',
]

# Seleccionamos que userprofile establezca el manejo de nuestros usuarios
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userprofile.User'
```

**2**. Creamos nuestro esquema de usuarios (roles `Patient`, `Medical`, y `Physiotherapist`)

```
# userprofile/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# Creamos la clase User que hereda de AbstractUser para adicionar
# tres atributos booleanos `is_medical`, `is_physiotherapist`, e `is_patient`
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Obtenemos los perfiles de cada usuario acorde a su tipo
    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile=self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_physiotherapist_profile(self):
        physiotherapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'physiotherapistprofile'):
            physiotherapist_profile = self.physiotherapistprofile
        return physiotherapist_profile

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        # Le decimos que estos campos vayan a la tabla auth_user
        # de igual nombre que la de django.contrib.auth

# Creamos un modelo Profile por cada rol o tipo de usuario 
# `Medical`, `Physiotherapist`, y `Patient` en donde en cada uno
# almacenaremos datos propios de cada rol de usuario
class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

He visto que al heredar de la clase `AbstractUser` para crear un modelo de usuario personalizado haciendo uso de `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, cuando efectuamos la primera migración, veo que no tenemos en el admin el modulo de User dado que lo hemos personalizado usando AbstractUser, y entonces es necesario registrarlo de forma manual en mi archivo admin.py con los atributos que maneja User en Django.

Al final del día, esto no es problema, se registra:

**3.** Registrando la clases/modelos `User`, `PatientProfile`, `MedicalProfile` y `PhysiotherapistProfile` en el admin de Django

***Detallar que en el caso de la clase*** `UserAdmin`, ***estamos heredando de*** `admin.ModelAdmin`

```
#userprofile/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, PhysiotherapistProfile, PatientProfile, MedicalProfile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Registramos el modelo User con los atributos por defecto que 
# Django provee, además de los atributos booleanos
# 'is_medical','is_patient','is_physiotherapist'
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =   ('id','username','password','first_name','last_name',
'email','is_staff','is_active','is_superuser',
'is_medical','is_patient','is_physiotherapist',
'last_login','date_joined')

# Registramos los modelos para cada tipo de usuario
@admin.register(PatientProfile)
class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name','active','user_id',)

@admin.register(MedicalProfile)
class MedicalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name','active','user_id',)

@admin.register(PhysiotherapistProfile)
class PhysiotherapistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name','active','user_id',)
```

Entonces al efectuar la migracion y cuando vamos al admin via web, detallamos que ya tenemos registrados los modelos `Users`, `PatientProfile`,`MedicalProfile`, y `PhysiotherapistProfile`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si entro a User, y edito un usuario puedo detallar que tengo adicionados los tres atributos booleanos `is_medical`, `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la misma manera cuando quiero crear un usuario en el administrador, tengo disponibles estos mismos tres atributos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero una de las cosas que detallo es que cuando estoy creando el usuario, el campo de texto **Password** no cifra el contenido que uno escribe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al almacenarlo así, pues por ende, también se visualiza en texto plano cuando miramos el listado de usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**4. Haciendo que el campo Password aparezca cifrado**

El admin de django y django en general utilizan [PBKDF2](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords) por defecto [como mecanismo o función de cifrado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)

[En este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514912/django-admin-not-hashing-custom-user-password) dicen que cuando registramos un modelo que herede de `AbstractUser`, en la clase que creamos para su registro en el archivo admin.py se debe es heredar de la clase `UserAdmin` y no de la admin.ModelAdmin que usamos para registrar los modelos en el administrador de Django. Al hacer esto, UserAdmin hace que mi campo password salga cifrado tanto para ser ingresado como cuando lo visualizo.

***Hacemos que nuestro modelo*** `User` ***personalizado herede de*** `UserAdmin` ***en lugar de*** `admin.ModelAdmin`

```
#userprofile/admin.py

# Hacemos que nuestro modelo User personalizado 
# herede de UserAdmin en lugar de admin.ModelAdmin
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','username','password','first_name','last_name','email','is_staff','is_active','is_superuser','is_medical','is_patient','is_physiotherapist','last_login','date_joined')
```

Después de hacer este cambio, si quiero crear un usuario el campo para ingresar el password sale protegido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi como tambien si quiero visualizarlo después de que he guardado dicho usuario creado anteriormente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El que heredemos de `UserAdmin` y no de `admin.ModelAdmin`, resuelve el problema para que los passwords salgan encriptados o "haseados" en el administrador de Django, pero entonces, ya heredando de UserAdmin, si voy a crear un nuevo usuario en User, no aparecen los campos o atributos que agregamos con anterioridad de `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist` y de `is_medical`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no aparecen estos atributos, en la creación del usuario, los cuales finalmente fueron la razón de crear un modelo personalizado y heredar de `AbstractUser`

Es lógico, no aparecen, porque ya estoy heredando de `UserAdmin` y asumo que al hacer esto, el sobreescribirá los campos que colocará en el administrador, los cuales asumo que son todos los de por defecto de Django menos los tres atributos booleanos de `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist` y de `is_medical` que yo he agregado antes.

Tengo esa inquietud.
¿Qué mecanismo habría para que con nuestro modelo personalizado quede el password hasheado en el admin? 
o
Que cuando heredemos de UserAdmin,¿cómo podemos tambien ver reflejados los campos adicionados en el admin como `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist` y de `is_medical`?

A veces me pregunto si son tan necesarios estos tres campos booleanos `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist` y de `is_medical` o con el solo hecho de tener `User` relacionado con `PatientProfile`, con `MedicalProfile` y con `PhysiotherapistProfile`, sería suficiente para tener estos tres roles de usuario y que cada uno tenga sus propios privilegios, [como lo tengo en este acercamiento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw4TD.png)

Claro esto es algo que yo debo probar.

Cualquier ayuda, consideración o aporte será altamente apreciado.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quiero comenzar diciendo que si existiera una medalla por posts largos te la ganarías :)

Vamos, el tema con el [`UserAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L43) es que está hecho exclusivamente para el usuario original de Django y usa formularios de creación y edición especiales para ese modelo. Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es heredarlos y modificarlos a tu gusto.

Puede que los nombres de nuestros archivos difieran ya que yo creé el proyecto en tu primera pregunta y estoy usando ese mismo proyecto.

```
# usuario/forms.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    UserChangeForm,
    UserCreationForm
)

from usuario.models import User


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
```

Una vez creados nuestros formularios que lo único que hacen es cambiar el modelo original a nuestro modelo customizado, debemos también crear un `UserAdmin` customizado para que use estos formularios:

```
# usuario/admin.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from usuario.forms import (
    CustomUserChangeForm,
    CustomUserCreationForm
)
from usuario.models import (
    MedicalProfile,
    PatientProfile,
    PhysiotherapistProfile,
    User
)


# Heredamos del UserAdmin original para usar nuestros formularios customizados
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (
            None, {
                'fields': (
                    'is_medical',
                    'is_physiotherapist',
                    'is_patient'
                )
            }
        ),
    )


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(CustomUserAdmin):
    list_display =  (
        'id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'is_staff',
        'is_active',
        'is_superuser',
        'is_medical',
        'is_patient',
        'is_physiotherapist',
        'last_login',
        'date_joined'
    )


@admin.register(PatientProfile)
class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'active',
        'user_id'
    )


@admin.register(MedicalProfile)
class MedicalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'active',
        'user_id'
    )


@admin.register(PhysiotherapistProfile)
class PhysiotherapistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'active',
        'user_id'
    )
```

Esto debería ser suficiente. Me comentas como te va.

Comment: perfecto. Segun entendí a vista superficial y con neuronas de 1:00 a.m., las clases UserChangeForm y UserCreationForm las usamos para aplicar UserChangeForm al modelo User (su formulario en el admin en este caso) que es el que queremos modificar. Y la clase UserCreationForm, querrá decir algo mas o menos como que esas modificaciones iniciales las apliquemos con UserCreationForm

Comment: Al importar estas dos clases forms personalizadas CustomUserChangeForm, CustomUserCreationForm en la clase CustomUserAdmin en forms.py, estamos aplicando las operaciones de cambiar y aplicar esos cambios en el formulario UserAdmin y esos cambios tienen que ver con los tres atributos booleanos is_patient, is_physiotherapist e is_patient.  La explicación puede ser mas elaborada, pero mas o menos lo entendí asi ¿verdad?. Sos un capo men.