# Trabajando con despliegue de campos en un formulario en base a una opción seleccionada - django-smart-selects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Estoy trabajando un formulario en el administrador de *Django*. La idea es trabajar un encadenamiento o secuencialidad en donde acorde a una opción seleccionada, se desplieguen unos campos y que éstos sean de múltiple selección.

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

- `Extremidad`: Tiene que ver con las extremidades superiores del cuerpo humano.
- `SegmentoAfectado`: Tiene que ver con segmentos corporales o partes del cuerpo humano. Para ser más concretos, los segmentos corporales que forman parte de una extremidad superior (mano, codo, antebrazo, escápula, hombro y el carpo o la muñeca).
- `Movimiento`: Tiene que ver con los movimientos o ejercicios que pueden realizarse para cada segmento corporal anterior que sea escogido. Es decir que estos movimientos son asociados a cada segmento afectado anteriormente mencionado (mano, codo, antebrazo, escápula, hombro y el carpo o la muñeca).

Finalmente, tengo un modelo llamado `EstructuraCorporal` (de pronto debería llamarlo de otra manera, pero esto es lo de menos) en el cual estoy reuniendo todos los modelos anteriores, con el objetivo de que este modelo me represente un formulario en el administrador de *Django* en donde un usuario realice la siguiente interacción para crear una estructura corporal:

1. Seleccionar una o más extremidades superiores- `Extremidad`. Solo habrán dos opciones, (puede ser izquierda o derecha), por lo cual lo máximo que se podrán seleccionar son dos. Considero que de esta selección no dependerá ningún despliegue de datos por lo que no generará encadenamiento, pero sí es clave poder seleccionar las dos y también una sola.
2. Seleccionar un segmento corporal afectado - `SegmentoAfectado` (mano, codo, antebrazo, escápula, hombro y el carpo o la muñeca). También es importante seleccionar 1 o todos, puede darse el caso de un paciente que tenga que tratarse de todos sus segmentos corporales. Por lo que acá es un campo de selección múltiple.
3. Seleccionar un movimiento - `Movimiento`. Los listados de movimientos se desplegarán acorde al segmento corporal afectado `SegmentoAfectado` que se ha seleccionado en el paso número **2**, es decir, que los tipos de movimientos o ejercicios que puedan darse, están asociados o dependerán del segmento corporal que se esté tratando el paciente.

Para este esquema de funcionamiento, y basándome en la forma en como funciona [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) además de algunas reglas de negocio, he elaborado el siguiente diagrama entidad relación que me parece pertinente compartirlo como información relevante en mi pregunta.

Es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las condiciones o "reglas de negocio" más importantes y que considero están reflejadas son:

- De una o dos extremidades superiores (`Extremidad`) se pueden seleccionar varios segmentos afectados (`SegmentoAfectado`).
  Una o dos extremidades presentan uno o muchos segmentos afectados o lo que es igual, Uno o muchos segmentos afectado puede estar presente en una o en las dos extremidades
- Uno o muchos segmentos afectados (`SegmentoAfectado`) pueden tener 1 o varios movimientos (`Movimientos`) o lo que es lo mismo uno o muchos movimientos estan presentes en uno o muchos segmentos afectados

Bueno, entonces acorde a lo anterior, la estructura de estos modelos que he mencionado en detalle es:

1. Modelo `Extremidad`. Lo tengo como un campo del tipo [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) debido a que solamente contamos con dos extremidades superiores, la izquierda y la derecha, por lo que las opciones son predeterminadas.

```py
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField

class Extremidad(models.Model):

    EXTREMIDAD_IZQUIERDA = 'Izquierda'
    EXTREMIDAD_DERECHA = 'Derecha'
    EXTREMIDAD_CHOICES = (
        (EXTREMIDAD_IZQUIERDA, u'Izquierda'),
        (EXTREMIDAD_DERECHA, u'Derecha'),
    )
    extremidad_superior = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=EXTREMIDAD_CHOICES, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return '%s' % self.extremidad_superior
```

2. Modelo `SegmentoAfectado`, el cual lo tengo como un campo del tipo `Field.choices` debido a que la cantidad de segmentos corporales que tenemos los seres humanos es limitada a 6 y es información que no va a cambiar.

```py
class SegmentoAfectado(models.Model):

    SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA = 'ESCAPULA'
    SEGMENTO_HOMBRO = 'HOMBRO'
    SEGMENTO_CODO = 'CODO'
    SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO = 'ANTEBRAZO'
    SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA = 'CARPO_MUNECA'
    SEGMENTO_MANO = 'MANO'
    SEGMENTO_CHOICES = (
        (SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA, u'Escápula'),
        (SEGMENTO_HOMBRO, u'Hombro'),
        (SEGMENTO_CODO, u'Codo'),
        (SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO, u'Antebrazo'),
        (SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA, u'Carpo/Muñeca'),
        (SEGMENTO_MANO, u'MANO'),
    )
    segmento_afectado = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=SEGMENTO_CHOICES, blank=False)

    # segmento_afectado = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
       return '%s' % self.segmento_afectado
```

3. Modelo `Movimiento`, en donde se realiza la relación `ManyToMany` con `SegmentoAfectado`.

```py
class Movimiento(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    segmento_corporal_asociado = models.ManyToManyField(SegmentoAfectado, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.nombre
```

4. Y la clase `EstructuraCorporal` que hace un "llamado" o relaciona a los objetos de tipo `Extremidad`, `SegmentoAfectado`, y `Movimiento`.

```py
class EstructuraCorporal(models.Model):
    extremidad_superior = models.ManyToManyField(Extremidad)
    segmento_afectado = models.ManyToManyField(SegmentoAfectado)
    movimiento = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Movimiento,
        chained_field = 'segmento_afectado',
        chained_model_field = 'segmento_corporal_asociado'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.segmento_afectado
```

Es en esta clase en donde se detalla el "encadenamiento" de selects para el comportamiento que deseo de ellos.

Mi pregunta, su texto se fué un poco larga, pero he querido dar un contexto completo de como es mi situación. Mi problema o inconveniente es uno solo y tiene que ver con lo siguiente:

- En este momento, puedo seleccionar la totalidad de las extremidades superiores (2) o una sola (derecha o izquierda).
- En este momento puedo seleccionar la totalidad de los segmentos corporales afectados (6) o cualquier combinación de ellos.
- En este momento, cuando selecciono un segmento corporal, se me despliegan los movimientos que dicho segmento corporal tiene asociados, y que son solo de él.

Pero cuando selecciono más de 1 segmento corporal afectado, deseo también que si selecciono dos segmentos afectados por ejemplo, en el `select choice` de Movimiento, se muestren los movimientos asociados a esos dos segmentos seleccionados.

Actualmente solo se está mostrando los movimientos asociados del primer segmento que selecciono, si selecciono un segundo segmento, no se actualiza el `box multiple` de movimientos sumando los del segundo que selecciono. Este comportamiento que menciono puede verse [en este video](https://cloudup.com/iyW19HrQ-If).

Al mirarla en el administrador, el comportamiento global de todo lo que he descrito puede verse [en este video](https://cloudup.com/iz8Z9pl0v1S) que he querido mostrar.

En síntesis lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que cuando seleccione un segundo segmento afectado (Opción **CODO** recuadro rojo número 1 en la gráfica anterior), se me desplieguen los movimientos de ejercicios asociados a ese segundo segmento afectado que es el **CODO**.

Actualmente solo se me desplegan los movimientos de Descenso, Elevación, Protracción y Retracción (opciones en el recuadro verde número 2 de la gráfica anterior) que son solo de la primera opción de segmento afectado seleccionada que es ESCÁPULA (recuadro rojo opción numero 1)

Esto se detalla en el primer video que referencio en mi pregunta.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto que deseo?

De alguna manera en el modelo `SegmentoAfectado` ¿debería poder saber que opción selecciono (algo parecido a `get_element_by_id` de *html*) para así monitorear cuando se haga una segunda opción y poder mostrar los movimientos de ambas opciones padres (segementos afectados)?

No sé si esto que pregunto tenga que ver con el recuadro azúl en mi imágen anterior en donde me dice `seleccionando.SegmentoAfectado.None`.

Y no sé en donde pueda establecer alguna lógica, dado que es mi admin el que la toma y la genera, pues no tengo acceso a ningún template...

¿De pronto con las clases `CustomUserChangeForm` `CustomUserCreationForm` y? Algo similar a lo que me decían [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072/heredando-de-abstractuser-django-admin-no-hashea-passwords-useradmin-no-mues). No tengo idea de como sería la verdad.

Otra inquietud que me intriga es que por ahora, estoy reflejando este comportamiento en el administrador de *Django*. Después tengo que reflejarlo en mi aplicación como tal, entonces:

¿Ya teniendo este comportamiento generado (con ayuda de `django-smart-select`), cuando genere mis forms desde un archivo `forms.py` y usando `models.Forms` será más sencillo o tendré que tener en cuenta esto también?

Agradezco que se hayan tomado el tiempo de interiorizar mi largo post, solo quería aportar todos los elementos necesarios para que mi inquietud sea bien dada a entender de mi parte. :)

Comment: Hola, nunca he usado `django-smart-selects` pero según leo en la documentación los campos `chained_field` y `chained_model_field` deberían usar el mismo modelo, es decir, tu `chained_field` apunta a `SegmentoAfectado` y por lo tanto `chained_model_field` debería apuntar a un campo de ese modelo pero tu estás usando el campo de otro modelo que es `segmento_corporal_asociado` y le pertenece al modelo `Movimiento`. Creo que el tema va por ahi

Comment: @César pero según entiendo la documentación para cuando son campos `ManyToMany` https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/blob/master/README.md#chained-manytomany-selects `chained_field` y `chained_model_field` corresponden a campos de distintos modelos, dice que `chained_field` es el campo sobre el mismo modelo que  debe ser encadenado, que en mi caso el modelo encadenado es `Movimientos` (ya que se trae la extremidad y el segmento y acorde a ellos me muestra los movimientos), entonces ubico en `chained_field` al atributo `segmento_afectado` pues este me dara los movimientos (Continúa)

Comment: Entonces, según entiendo la documentación para cuando son campos  `ManyToMany`, el modelo que encadena es `EstructuraCorporal` (pues se trae a `SegmentoAfectado` y a `Movimientos`) y el modelo encadenado es Movimiento, dado que acorde al objeto seleccionado de `SegmentoAfectado`, se generan los objetos Movimiento que estan asociados al SegmentoAfectado

Comment: Y `chained_model_field` indica  el campo sobre el modelo encadenado, que es el modelo Movimiento (en él hay un campo `segmento_corporal_asociado`, que corresponde al modelo enlazado por el `chained_field`, campo el cual es `segmento_afectado`, el cual enlaza a traves de `ManyToManyField` al modelo `SegmentoAfectado`), entonces en síntesis en chained_model_field acorde a su caracterización se coloca el campo segmento_corporal_asociado que es un campo del modelo `SegmentoAfectado` y en chained_field a `segmento_afectado` que es un campo propio del modelo que encadena (`EstructuraCorporal`)

Comment: No se si me hice entender, pero entendería que ambos atributos `chained_field` y `chained_model_field` referencian campos de diferentes modelos, pero esos campos apuntan al mismo modelo, en este caso `SegmentoAfectado` . En esta imagen https://cldup.com/QXaLgMGVQ8.png en donde `chained_field` en rojo apunta al atributo que llama al modelo `SegmentoAfectado` y en naranja `chained_model_field` apunta a `segmento_corporal_asociado` que es del modelo Movimiento (el encadenado) y en él este referencia a `SegmentoAfectado` también. No se si di muchas vueltas con esto para hacerme entender :(

Comment: Creoq ue smart-selects no funciona con campos en un mismo modelo, a menos que esos campos sean llaves foráneas a otros modelos.

Comment: @SalahAdDin si funciona, es decir como lo tengo me funciona para que me muestre los movimientos de un determinado segmento afectado que seleccione, pero quiero que si selecciono mas de un segmento afectado, me muestre los movimientos de esos segmentos, solo me muestra el primero.

Comment: Supondría entonces que esa capacidad no la tiene ahora el paquete, puedes reportar este error en su github para pedir que lo resuelvan. Si encuentras como ayudar, mucho mejor.

Comment: @SalahAdDin es cierto, [en esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5723/1005) esta la razón principal por la que no fuciona lo que deseo. Y hay alternativas de solución. Ya me toca es empezar a evaluarlas y trabajar en ellas.

Comment: @bgarcial, no olvides publicar tu solución por aquí :D

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene un desarrollo realmente exhaustivo del problema, uno de los más detallados que vi. Sin embargo, creo que el desarrollo es demasiado amplio, tanto que dudo que alguien tenga el tiempo suficiente para abarcarlo. La idea que se busca en las preguntas del sitio es que presenten un problema acotado, un ejemplo mínimo. Te recomiendo dos opciones: o contratar a alguien que lo resuelva, o leer como crear un [mcve] y replantear el problema. Mientras tanto, estoy votando para dejar en pausa como demasiado amplia.

Comment: @Mariano agradezco mucho tu respuesta, tendré en cuenta esto del ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable, es muy ilustrativo esa descripción. El issue que puse en aquel entonces, hace ya algún tiempo fue abordado por una persona y contribuyó al master de django-smart-selects https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/pull/139 Muchas gracias por las sugerencias y recomendaciones

Comment: @bgarcial Me alegro que se haya solucionado. No quiero que se malinterprete, la pregunta puede ser más que interesante, es sólo la forma en la que se plantea y el nivel de abstracción que creo que escapa al alcance del sitio. No obstante, me encantaría ver una pregunta-respuesta que expliquen ese issue en particular.

Comment: @Mariano para nada, tus consideraciones son importantes, y creo que teniéndolas en cuenta, si me estaba extendiendo mucho en el detalle en la pregunta original. En cuanto a la respuesta, intentaré sacarle el tiempo para darla acorde a los aportes de contribución de la persona quien resolvió este "issue", la pregunta fue larga porque ilustra las secciones de código en donde se debe resolver el problema, aunque el autor quien lo resolvió fue más allá de esas secciones que yo referencié aquí. Pero si puede ser ilustrativa para quien llegué acá. Tus consideraciones son siempre bienvenidas. :)