# Como establecer permisos a un Perfil según relacion que tenga

Tags: django, django-models

Hola estoy desarrollando un app e django 2.0.6 pero tengo duda a la hora de establecer permisos.

El problema es que tengo un modelo User que hereda de `AbstractBaseUser` y creo un un perfil *`ProfesorPerfil`* con una relación **OneToOne** con **User**; el modelo *`ProfesorPerfil`* tiene relaciones con otros Modelos como *`Disciplina`*(un profesor es el jefe de una disciplina y una disciplina tiene un jefe que es un profesor).

Yo quisiera establecer un permiso para todos los jefes de disciplina; pero no tengo ninguna tabla que me almacene todos los jefes de disciplina; solo la relación One to One entre *`ProfesorPerfil`* y *`Disciplina`*.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Apellidos')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Correo', unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Dia de Union', auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_profesor = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Profesor', default=False)
    is_estudiante = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Estudiante', default=False)

    object = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'usuario'
        verbose_name_plural = 'usuarios'
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        ordering = ('nombre', 'apellido')

    def get_profesor_profile(self):
        profesor = None
        if hasattr(self,'profesorperfil'):
            profesor = self.profesorperfil
        return profesor

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.nombre, self.apellido)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.nombre

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('indexCarg')

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
```

---

```
class ProfesorPerfil(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name='Teléfono', max_length=20)
    categoria_doc = models.ForeignKey(Categoria_Docente, related_name='profesores', verbose_name=u'Categoría Docente',
                                      on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    categorias_cientficas = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria_Cientifica, related_name='profesores_cat_cientifica')
    titulo = models.ForeignKey(Titulo, related_name='profesores', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    # asignaturas_imaprtidas = models.ManyToManyField(Asignatura, through='ProfesorAsignatura')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profesor'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profesores'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.nombre + ' ' + self.user.apellido
```

---

```
class Disciplina(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    horas_limite = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Horas Límites')
    jefe_disciplina = models.ForeignKey(ProfesorPerfil, related_name='disciplinas', related_query_name='disciplina',
                                        verbose_name='Jefe de Disciplina', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan_Estudio,verbose_name='Plan de Estudio', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    #                          related_name='disciplinas',related_query_name='disciplina')
    # carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carrera,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='disciplinas')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cargadocente:list_disciplinas')
```

Comment: Hola @Rolando. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/930/roles-de-usuarios-en-django