# ¿Cuando extender el modelo Users de Django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-models

Estoy desarrollando una API con DRF pero me surge la duda de si es mejor extender el modelo Users de Django o crear un nuevo modelo con los campos que necesitare, ademas de que la API esta pensada para manejar distintos tipos de usuario.

Comment: te sugiero leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/930/roles-de-usuarios-en-django..

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar un modelo distinto a `User` de django (sin extenderlo) es una mala idea. `django` está plagado de referencias a este modelo así como `DRF` o paquetes para `django` que probablemente uses.

No obstante `django` sabe que quizás necesites proveer de más funcionalidades a este modelo, por lo que te permite hacerlo de forma sencilla

myapp/models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Usuarios(AbstractUser):
    def my_custom_method(self):
        pass
```

myapp/settings.py

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Usuarios'
```

Este comportamiento es conocido por cualquier paquete que se precie. Por ejemplo, `rest_framework.authtoken.Token.user` luce así:

```py
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
```

Si la lógica de empresa va a ser compleja, lo más probable es que necesites extender el modelo usuarios de django ya que éste modelo va a estar en todos los requests y vas a poder acceder a métodos útiles. Ejemplo:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_A():
            return A
        return B
```

Dicho esto, los dos motivos por los que querrías extender este modelo son:

- 1) Necesitas modificar la forma de hacer login (usar email en lugar de username)
- 2) Necesitas métodos en el modelo que te faciliten la vida durante el desarrollo

En caso de que necesites añadir campos a la DB lo más recomendable es utilizar un modelo a parte, `UserProfile` con una relación OneToOne al modelo `User`, ya que ésta información extra estará disponible si la necesitas y no forzarás a moverla de la DB en cada request (recuerda, la instancia de `User` está disponible en cada petición del usuario)