# asesoramiento sobre gestión de roles en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de trabajar con un sistema de roles que permite desde el registro de usuarios, seleccionar el rol al que desea pertenecer, el problema es que no obtengo la mejor manera de hacerlo porque cuando quiero hacer validaciones genera muchos errores, investigando un poco me di cuenta de que los grupos son más eficientes en este sentido o bien, creo que sí, si alguien pudiera darme algún consejo y un enlace a un ejemplo de cómo manejar esto, estaría muy agradecido.

Este es mi código:

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    is_administrador = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_satelite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_administrador(self):
        administrador = None
        if hasattr(self, 'administrador'):
            administrador = self.administrador
        return administrador

    def get_satelite(self):
        satelite = None
        if hasattr(self, 'satelite'):
            satelite = self.satelite
        return satelite

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class Administrador(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagen = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Satelite(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagen = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    nivel_acadademico = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.usuario)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Usuario)
def asignar_rol(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        if instance.is_administrador:
            Administrador.objects.get_or_create(usuario=instance)
        elif instance.is_satelite:
            Satelite.objects.get_or_create(usuario=instance)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Roles de usuarios en Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/930/roles-de-usuarios-en-django)

Comment: realmente no me sirve pues cuando realizo el registro la contraseña no se guarda de forma correcta, y mas aun cuando quiero realizar la modificacion de cada usuario registo no lo permite, y el acceso a la pagino tampoco lo permite.

Comment: se que se puedo hashear la contraseña pero si lo hago todos los medelos que permiten el registro a los demas modelos se pierden lo he intentado poner de forma manual en el admin pero aun asi no se genera nada.

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver aquí la contraseña del usuario, pues Django ya se encarga de eso. Por otra parte quieres que en el registro de usuario, un usuario pueda escojer su rol? es decir un tipo `<select>` donde escoja su rol o un radio button donde escoja el rol, algo así? y a su ves identificar a que rol pertenece un usuario?

Comment: no exactamente pues aunque se puede crear el registro de los usuarios de forma que la contraseña se queda hasheada con from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm y en el admin from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin o algo parecido, pero si se hace de esa forma las otras tablas las cuales permite la relacion con distintos roles, se pierde y no hay forma de recuperar esas relaciones anterior y el select es lo de menos pues si logro la relacion, pero al querer acceder sesion con esos usuarios no lo permite ni menos modificarlos.

Comment: No te entiendo. Quieres un registro normal (que no sea en el admin de Django, por supuesto), donde un usuario pueda escojer un rol? y listo?

Comment: de los dos tanto como el usuario normal al crear su registro pueda eligir su rol, como el admin que tambien pueda crear un usuario y asignarle un rol.

Comment: Ok acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera (usando `choices`), pues me parece mas sencillo y mucho, pero mucho mas limpio:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('administrador', 'Administrador'),
        ('satelite', 'Satelite'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = ROLE_CHOICES)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'role']

    def get_role(self):
        return getattr(self, self.role, None)
```

*(Recuerda que el modelo de usuario personalizado es `User`, no `Usuario`, puedes cambiarle el nombre, pero te recomiendo siempre programar en ingles)*

Así, un usuario podrá escoger un rol y una señal se encargaría de crear la relación en base al campo `role`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def set_user_rol(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        if instance.role == 'administrador':
            Administrador.objects.create(usuario = instance)
        else:
            Satelite.objects.create(usuario = instance)
```

Ahora, para acceder a la relación o a la instancia relacionada, hay dos maneras, una es utilizando el método `get_role`:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(...)
>>> user.get_role()
<Satelite: ...>
```

La segunda forma, seria así:

```
>>> if user.role == 'administracion':
...     related_instance = user.administracion
... else:
...     related_instance = user.satelite
...
>>>
```

Evidentemente, la primera forma es la mas optima, unos ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> user.get_role()
> <Administracion: ...>
> >>> user.get_role().razon_social
> '...'
> ```
>
> El ejemplo anterior seria exactamente igual a lo siguiente:
>
> ```
> >>> user.administracion
> <Administracion: ...>
> >>> user.administracion.razon_social
> '...'
> ```

Y para saber, que rol tiene un usuario es simple:

```
>>> user1.role
'administracion'
>>> user2.role
'satelite'
```

---

Listo, ahora, seria hacer que en los formularios, aparezca el campo `role`, el formulario de registro normal seria así:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('role',)
```

Eso seria todo, puedes personalizarlo mas, pero el campo `role` estará ahí, y seria casi igual con un formulario de edición de usuario (`UserChangeForm`).

---

> **Cabe recalcar que si o si, al momento de crear un usuario debe tener un valor el campo role, así se crean las relaciones y se evitan
> múltiples errores!!**

---

Ahora los formularios del admin (archivo `admin.py`):

```
@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Roles', {'fields': ('role',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('role',)}),
    )
```

Aquí solo añadimos el campo `role` a los formularios del admin (formulario de añadir un usuario y de edición de un usuario).

Una imagen de como quedaría el formulario de *"**añadir un usuario**"* en el admin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una imagen de como quedaría el formulario de *"**edición de un usuario**"* en el admin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y listo, eso seria todo. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: bueno esto es mundo nuevo para mi, disculpa genera un error name 'Satelite' is not defined

Comment: ya mire el error muchas gracias disculpen men donde se encuentra todo esto sabes mucho me has sido de gran ayuda.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte!, todo esto lo puedes encontrar en la documentación de Django, es muy pero muy completa y super fácil de entender.